# PyQT: how to hide every object in a dialogue window

Tags: python, pyqt

I'd like to use .hide() method on every object in my window. Is there some sort of .hideall() function or a way to iterate over every object like:

```
for object in dialogue.objects:
    object.hide()
```

Comment: No sir, I did it another way.